regex, remove everything before first underscore
i have this string grafana-stack_alloy and require everything after the first underscore
alloy.
I need the result as a group $1. Tried this one, but it failed. (?:)?([^_]+)*$.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
I am testing this:
        rule {
        action        = "replace"
        source_labels = [
            "__meta_docker_container_label_com_docker_swarm_service_name",
        ]
        regex        = "^(?:;*)?([^;]+).*$" work but wrong
        //regex      = "[^_]+.$" ----> not work
        //regex      = "([^_]+)$" ----> not work
        replacement  = argument.namespace.value + "/$1"
        target_label = "job"
    }

It is about the Grafana Agent with relabel-regex:
Grafana prometheus.relabel which use Google's RE2 as its regex engine.
Thanks in advance

(?:) looks weird. Isn't (?:foo) a non-capturing version of (foo) in Perl regexes? But that would make (?:) a zero-length match... What's the intent here?

These will get everything after the last underscore.
_([^_]+)$

or
^.*_([^_]+)$

If you want everything after the first underscore:
^[^_]*_(.+)$

or change the first * to a + if you don't want leading underscores.
If you want to also eliminate the second underscore in a double underscore but get everything after that, try
^[^_]*_+(.+)$

If you want a more specific match, maybe you want
grafana-stack_([^_]+)$

If none of these do what you want, you'll need to give more of the surrounding context than the string you gave.

As far as Grafana use Golang regexes flavor, you need to modify the regex to:
([^_])*$

See online demo explanations
Official doc mention Golang too:

expression needs to be a Go RE2 regex string.


Note that this would match even if there is no _ and also matches the empty string. Not a problem with the OP's input string but might be worth mentioning.

Also, this gives everything after the last underscore, he wanted everything after the first underscore...although there's no difference for the sample string.

As the "replacement" is:

replacement  = argument.namespace.value + "/$1"


That implies that what is matched by the regexp is replaced with that.
In grafana-stack_alloy, your ([^_]+)$ regexp will correctly match the alloy part after _ and capture it into $1, but because the whole regexp matches only that, after replacement, you'll get:
grafana-stack_<argument.namespace.value>/alloy

If what you want the result to be after replacement is only <argument.namespace.value>/alloy, then you need the regex to match the whole input and out of that capture the part after _.
As RE2 support perl's *? non-greedy repetition operator, that can be just:
^.*?_(.*)$

The anchors (^, $) are not even needed as that regexp is guaranteed to match the whole input as long as it contains at least one _ (and not match at all with or without anchor if there's no _).
